# Do we have $\underline{\operatorname{Ext}}^i_\text{fppf}(\mathbb{G}_a,\mathbb{G}_m)=0$ for $i>0$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, algebraic-groups, sheaf-theory

Let $k$ be a characteristic zero field and consider the category $(\mathsf{Sch}/k)_\text{fppf}$ of schemes over $k$ with the fppf topology. I know that $\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(\mathbb{G}_a,\mathbb{G}_m)=\widehat{\mathbb{G}}_a$. (Here we see all the groups as abelian sheaves on $(\mathsf{Sch}/k)_\text{fppf}$.)

**Is it true that the Ext sheaves $\underline{\operatorname{Ext}}^i(\mathbb{G}_a,\mathbb{G}_m)$ vanish for $i>0$?**

I know that [Br] shows that the Ext *groups* $\operatorname{Ext}^i(\mathbb{G}_a,\mathbb{G}_m)$ vanish for $i>0$. But I don't know how to deduce what I want from this. (This is very close to the problem in [Vanishing of $\text{Ext}^2$ sheaf from abelian variety to multiplicative group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247161/vanishing-of-textext2-sheaf-from-abelian-variety-to-multiplicative-group).)

Reference:

- [Br] L. Breen - [Extensions of Abelian Sheaves and Eilenberg–Maclane Algebras](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01389887)

Comment: Dear @LSpice, do you mind explaining why you changed the \textsf to \mathsf?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444727/do-we-have-underline-operatornameexti-textfppf-mathbbg-a-mathbbg#comment1148345_444727), because `\textsf` is semantically for use in text and `\mathsf` is semantically for use in math.  Of course in MathJax (as opposed to TeX) the distinction is otiose, and may even result in identical rendering (I don't know), but I figured it was better to be semantically correct while I was adding the links.  But, if you don't like it, then feel free to revert (although hopefully leaving the links), and please accept my apologies for an unwanted edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is false, see Remark 2.2.16 of [Rosengarten - Tate Duality In Positive Dimension Over Function Fields](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.00522.pdf#page34) in which a nontrivial local extension of $\mathbb{G}_a$ by $\mathbb{G}_m$ is constructed. However, the same paper shows that the first Ext-sheaf vanishes in positive characteristic.

Comment: Your link is anchored at p. 34.  Because my browser doesn't obey that directive, I don't know whether that links to physical or logical page 34, but the actual remark seems to be logical page 29 = physical page 31.

Comment: Wow that's surprising. Do you know something about the higher ext sheaves or about the case of the formal additive group?

Comment: Something sounds off. There is a general rule of thumb that anything which holds in enough positive characteristics holds in characteristic 0. What about this result is allowed to violate that rule of thumb?

Comment: @Gabriel I agree it’s surprising to me too. No unfortunately I don’t know anything about the case of the formal group

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd To me it’s very counterintuitive that the bad behavior occurs is characteristic 0 in this case. However, I think it’s essentially due to the existence of nontrivial homomorphisms from the additive group to the multiplicative group

Comment: @Exitpath, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444727/do-we-have-underline-operatornameexti-textfppf-mathbbg-a-mathbbg#comment1148560_444742), there are still no non-trivial homomorphisms from the additive group to the multiplicative group in characteristic $0$.  (Such a homomorphism is dual to a map $k[X, X^{-1}] \to k[X]$, which must send $X$ to a unit, hence a constant.)

Comment: @LSpice My apologies for being unclear, I just meant for a non-reduced $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $A$ we have the homomorphisms $exp(rT)$ where $r$ is a nilpotent. A map like this seems to be important in the construction of the counterexample

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd Actually, reading the counterexample a little more carefully, the characteristic zero assumption seems to be used in an essential way when showing that if an extension splits fppf locally then it splits etale locally

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444727/do-we-have-underline-operatornameexti-textfppf-mathbbg-a-mathbbg/444742#comment1148584_444742), as I was commenting it occurred to me that you might mean to work over a ring rather than over a field, but then surely positive characteristic can behave badly again, using your same example, as long as there are nilpotents of class ${}< p$?

Comment: @LSpice Agreed! Your comment is why I responded again to Theo Johnson-Freyd amending the reason I thought the characteristic zero case was different. The existence of these homomorphisms can't on its own explain the discrepancy for the reason you point out